# MYSQL query for find rows not overlapping other table

Tags: mysql, join, scheduler

I have been stuck on this query for far too long. I always get close but not exact.  It seems simple.  Need to find rows in a table showing all available time slots that do not overlap any row from a table with appts scheduled.  We need the computer to auto-fill a schedule with no overlap.

```
mysql> select * from existingApptsToNotOverlap order by startTime;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| startTime           | endTime             |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | 2015-05-28T12:15:00 |
| 2015-05-29T10:15:00 | 2015-05-29T10:45:00 |
| 2015-05-29T11:00:00 | 2015-05-29T11:45:00 |
| 2015-05-29T12:00:00 | 2015-05-29T12:45:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from allAvailableSlots;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| startTime           | endTime             |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2015-05-28T09:00:00 | 2015-05-28T09:45:00 |
| 2015-05-28T09:15:00 | 2015-05-28T10:00:00 |
| 2015-05-28T09:30:00 | 2015-05-28T10:15:00 |
| 2015-05-28T09:45:00 | 2015-05-28T10:30:00 |
| 2015-05-28T10:00:00 | 2015-05-28T10:45:00 |
| 2015-05-28T10:15:00 | 2015-05-28T11:00:00 |
| 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | 2015-05-28T11:15:00 |
| 2015-05-28T10:45:00 | 2015-05-28T11:30:00 |
| 2015-05-28T11:00:00 | 2015-05-28T11:45:00 |
| 2015-05-29T09:00:00 | 2015-05-29T09:45:00 |
| 2015-05-29T09:15:00 | 2015-05-29T10:00:00 |
| 2015-05-29T09:30:00 | 2015-05-29T10:15:00 |
| 2015-05-29T09:45:00 | 2015-05-29T10:30:00 |
| 2015-05-29T10:00:00 | 2015-05-29T10:45:00 |
| 2015-05-29T10:15:00 | 2015-05-29T11:00:00 |
| 2015-05-29T10:30:00 | 2015-05-29T11:15:00 |
| 2015-05-29T10:45:00 | 2015-05-29T11:30:00 |
| 2015-05-29T11:00:00 | 2015-05-29T11:45:00 |
| 2015-05-30T09:00:00 | 2015-05-30T09:45:00 |
| 2015-05-30T09:15:00 | 2015-05-30T10:00:00 |
| 2015-05-30T09:30:00 | 2015-05-30T10:15:00 |
| 2015-05-30T09:45:00 | 2015-05-30T10:30:00 |
| 2015-05-30T10:00:00 | 2015-05-30T10:45:00 |
| 2015-05-30T10:15:00 | 2015-05-30T11:00:00 |
| 2015-05-30T10:30:00 | 2015-05-30T11:15:00 |
| 2015-05-30T10:45:00 | 2015-05-30T11:30:00 |
| 2015-05-30T11:00:00 | 2015-05-30T11:45:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
27 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is my latest attempt (after many other attempts):

```
mysql> select * from (select *, IF((slotStart<apptStart and slotEnd<apptStart) or (slotStart>apptEnd and slotEnd>apptEnd),1,0) as exclude from (select allSlots.startTime as slotStart, allSlots.endTime as slotEnd, existingAppts.startTime as apptStart, existingAppts.endTime as apptEnd from allSlots left join existingAppts on date(allSlots.startTime)=date(existingAppts.startTime) order by allSlots.startTime) as A group by slotStart, exclude desc) as B where exclude=0 group by slotStart;
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| slotStart           | slotEnd             | apptStart           | apptEnd             | exclude |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 2015-05-28T09:45:00 | 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | 2015-05-28T12:15:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-28T10:00:00 | 2015-05-28T10:45:00 | 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | 2015-05-28T12:15:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-28T10:15:00 | 2015-05-28T11:00:00 | 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | 2015-05-28T12:15:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | 2015-05-28T11:15:00 | 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | 2015-05-28T12:15:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-28T10:45:00 | 2015-05-28T11:30:00 | 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | 2015-05-28T12:15:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-28T11:00:00 | 2015-05-28T11:45:00 | 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | 2015-05-28T12:15:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-29T09:30:00 | 2015-05-29T10:15:00 | 2015-05-29T10:15:00 | 2015-05-29T10:45:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-29T09:45:00 | 2015-05-29T10:30:00 | 2015-05-29T10:15:00 | 2015-05-29T10:45:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-29T10:00:00 | 2015-05-29T10:45:00 | 2015-05-29T10:15:00 | 2015-05-29T10:45:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-29T10:15:00 | 2015-05-29T11:00:00 | 2015-05-29T10:15:00 | 2015-05-29T10:45:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-29T10:30:00 | 2015-05-29T11:15:00 | 2015-05-29T11:00:00 | 2015-05-29T11:45:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-29T10:45:00 | 2015-05-29T11:30:00 | 2015-05-29T11:00:00 | 2015-05-29T11:45:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-29T11:00:00 | 2015-05-29T11:45:00 | 2015-05-29T11:00:00 | 2015-05-29T11:45:00 |       0 |
| 2015-05-30T09:00:00 | 2015-05-30T09:45:00 | NULL                | NULL                |       0 |
| 2015-05-30T09:15:00 | 2015-05-30T10:00:00 | NULL                | NULL                |       0 |
| 2015-05-30T09:30:00 | 2015-05-30T10:15:00 | NULL                | NULL                |       0 |
| 2015-05-30T09:45:00 | 2015-05-30T10:30:00 | NULL                | NULL                |       0 |
| 2015-05-30T10:00:00 | 2015-05-30T10:45:00 | NULL                | NULL                |       0 |
| 2015-05-30T10:15:00 | 2015-05-30T11:00:00 | NULL                | NULL                |       0 |
| 2015-05-30T10:30:00 | 2015-05-30T11:15:00 | NULL                | NULL                |       0 |
| 2015-05-30T10:45:00 | 2015-05-30T11:30:00 | NULL                | NULL                |       0 |
| 2015-05-30T11:00:00 | 2015-05-30T11:45:00 | NULL                | NULL                |       0 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see several timeslots on 5/29 are included that should not be as they conflict with an existing event on that date.

Is this even possible with queries or does it require application logic on the result sets?

Comment: will get to actual question in a second. but did you ever think to add a `id int not null auto_increment primary key` to these tables ?

Comment: How often does this run? I'd normally just extract all your appointments for the day, then loop through and check each against the existing appointments table. Depends on resource usage, how many people are doing this at a time, etc. It would simplify the code. Obtuse queries are a pain to support.

Comment: Just another thought. If this is any type of real time scheduling, you might want to create a table of available slots, and remove them or lock them somehow when the client is looking at them. That way you don't take the risk of double allocating slots.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  To address them:  The full production tables do have auto_increment index fields (as well as several others).  It runs only when a person needs to add something to the schedule, but there could be any number of users.  The backend where this logic would take place is in Node.js so the looping thing was trying to be avoided due to the single process loop while handling multiple requests.  Still, I might have to go there.  The "table" of available slots is actually not a physical table but an on-the-fly (select) for whatever date range they specified on an earlier step.

Comment: This query gets close as well but the ON clause for the join is too simple as it does not take into account overlaps or cases where the start times are not exactly equal.  `select t1.startTime from allSlots t1 left join existingAppts t2 on t2.startTime=t1.startTime where t2.endTime is NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

I think I have it.  This appears to work.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
select t1.startTime,t1.endTime,t2.endTime as appt from allSlots t1 left join existingAppts t2 on ((t1.startTime >= t2.startTime and t1.startTime < t2.endTime) or (t1.endTime > t2.startTime and t1.endTime <= t2.endTime)) where t2.endTime IS NULL order by t1.startTime;

+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| startTime           | endTime             | appt |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 2015-05-28T09:00:00 | 2015-05-28T09:45:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-28T09:15:00 | 2015-05-28T10:00:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-28T09:30:00 | 2015-05-28T10:15:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-28T09:45:00 | 2015-05-28T10:30:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-29T09:00:00 | 2015-05-29T09:45:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-29T09:15:00 | 2015-05-29T10:00:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-29T09:30:00 | 2015-05-29T10:15:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-30T09:00:00 | 2015-05-30T09:45:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-30T09:15:00 | 2015-05-30T10:00:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-30T09:30:00 | 2015-05-30T10:15:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-30T09:45:00 | 2015-05-30T10:30:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-30T10:00:00 | 2015-05-30T10:45:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-30T10:15:00 | 2015-05-30T11:00:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-30T10:30:00 | 2015-05-30T11:15:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-30T10:45:00 | 2015-05-30T11:30:00 | NULL |
| 2015-05-30T11:00:00 | 2015-05-30T11:45:00 | NULL |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```